# Unable to load Angular Apps

Tags: angular, angularjs, mean

I am trying to run some existing angular apps, but always gets this error while using npm start:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'E:\mean-stack-example-main\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs' imported from E:\mean-stack-example-main\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\index.js
[1] See "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-vCkIMl\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[1] E:\mean-stack-example-main\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
[1]     setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
[1]                              ^
[1]
[1] Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\mean-stack-example-main\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs' imported from E:\mean-stack-example-main\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\index.js
[1]     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
[1]     at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)
[1]     at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:916:10)
[1]     at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)
[1]     at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
[1]     at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
[1]     at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
[1]     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
[1]     at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
[1]   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
[1] }
```

If I try to run a prebuilt app like the new-app from angular it runs okay, But running any project from github, it gives this error. Also, I had some previous apps, it gives the same error on those as well.
What should I do?

Trying to run existing angular apps, but unable to do so.

Comment: Have you ran `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes definitely , I did that but unable to load